windowing in CP-OFDM in MATLAB toolbox function nrOFDMMOdulate
In the function windowing inside the OFDMModulate function in MATLAB R2024a , why it is appending E samples at front  from somewhere in middle of the signal and not from the end ?
    window = raised_cosine_window(N_tot,E);
    extended = [symbol(N_u-E + (1:E),1:P); symbol];

